# Install4j - How to check if a file exists in conditional expression?

Tags: java, install4j

For example I can do to  test if the system is a 64-bit Windows system:

```
return Util.isWindows() && Util.is64BitWindows();
```

My question now is how do I check to see if say "c:\test\myTestFile.txt" exists in a specific directory on the computer within the Install4j conditional expression?

Comment: `new File("c:\test\myTestFile.txt").exists();`?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I didn't realize you could call Java code directly from the installer. Very cool feature. The specific code is: new java.io.File("C:\\temp").exists())); Please go ahead and answer it and I'll give you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new java.io.File("C:/temp").exists();
```